# How can I solve this complex inequality?

Tags: complex-numbers, triangle-inequality

I'm starting to study complex numbers right now, and then I came across with this problem:

$$\frac{|z^m|}{|z^{n} +1|} < \frac{|R^m|}{|R^{n}-1|}$$
where $|z|=R$

I know that everything starts with triangle inequality, but I don't know how to continue the resolution. Can anyone help me? Any tips?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your question, it isn't very clear what you are writing

Comment: $|z^{m}| \leq R^{m}$ and $|z^{n}+1| \geq |R^{n}-1|$.

Comment: Isn’t $|z^m|=R^m$ @geetha290krm?

Comment: The numerators on both sides are equal.
For the denominators, we may take $\omega=z^n$, then $R^n=|z^n|=|\omega|$. We are done if we can prove that $|\omega+1| \gt ||\omega|-1|$.

Comment: Using the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)  $\|x−y\|≥\left|\|x\|-\|y\|\right|$ with $x=z^n$ and $y=−1$, we get nearly what you want. But you may have equality (e.g. if $z^n=-2$). Moreover, you should assume $R\ne1$.